# How do I find the particular solution to this ODE?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm currently stuck on finding a solution for the following ODE:

$$ y'' +2y' +5y = e^{-x}(60\sin(x) + 57\cos(x))$$

The homogeneous part is fairly easy, just solving the auxiliary equation:

$ y_h = e^{-x}(C_1\cos(2x)) + C_2\sin(2x))$

But when it comes down to the particular part, I'm lost...

Symbolab is giving me:

$ y_h = e^{-x}(19\cos(x)) + 20\sin(x))$

But I have no clue how come.

The teacher will not provide any solutions and I have this test coming up in 2 days. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

use the undetermined coefficient method

so 
$$y_p=e^{-x}(A\cos x+B\sin x)$$
$$y'_p=e^{-x}((B-A)\cos x-(A+B)\sin x)$$

$$y''_p=e^{-x}(2A\sin x-2B\cos x)$$
then plug it into the original D.E to get
$$3Ae^{-x} \cos x+3Be^{-x} \sin x=e^{-x}(60 \sin(x) + 57 \cos(x))$$now complete it

Comment: Hmm what's strange is that I got A = 14.81 and B = -3/4. I double checked all my calculations.

Comment: See the answer above

Answer (score 0):

This particular solution can be obtained by using a function similar to the inhomogeneity (also known as the form of the right-hand side).

Use the ansatz
$$y_p=a e^{-x}\sin x + b e^{-x}\cos x$$

and plug it into the differential equation. Then compare the coefficients of similar terms to determine the coefficients $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Hmm it seems like if I used the opposite coefficients, so $A$ for $cos(x)$ and $B$ for $sin(x)$ and got $A = 14.81$ and $B = \frac{-3} {4}$. Is my answer wrong because I've used the opposite terms?

Comment: @dsalineUse Wolfram alpha to verify your solution.